# cocos2d v3 CCPhysicsBody cornerRadius

Tags: cocos2d-iphone, cornerradius

I try to create a CCPhysicsBody with a cornerRadius but I can't make it work.
Here my code :

```
CCSprite * player = [[CCSprite alloc] initWithImageNamed:@"ship.png"];
player.position  = ccp(200, 100);
player.physicsBody = [CCPhysicsBody bodyWithRect:(CGRect){CGPointZero, player.contentSize} 
                                    cornerRadius:5.0f]; 
player.physicsBody.collisionGroup = @"playerGroup";
player.physicsBody.collisionType  = @"playerCollision";
[physicsWorld addChild:player];
```

I tried several values (1, 30, 10.0f ....) without effect.
When I use `physicsWorld.debugDraw = YES;` the corners are never rounded.

Am I missing something ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using Cocos2d v3.0 it's not yet developed. In v3.1 it's neither included, maybe in future releases.

Comment: Thank you. A more detailled answer here : http://forum.cocos2d-swift.org/t/ccphysicsbody-cornerradius-works/12639